# An Application of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f :\Bbb R→ \Bbb R$ be given by $f(x) := x^{n}$ for some $n ∈ \Bbb N$. If $b$ is a
positive real number, show that there exists a unique positive real
number $a$ such that $a^{n} = b$.

My solution:

Let us choose an interval $[c,d]\subset \Bbb R$ such that $c,d>0$ and $d>c$. Now in this closed interval $f(x)$ is continuous since it is a product ($n$ times) of a continuous function $F(x)=x$. Hence $f(x)$ is continuous in $[c,d]$. Also, $f(d)>f(c)$. By Archimedean Property of reals, we can find $f(c)<b<f(d)$. By Intermediate Value Theorem, $\exists$ a point $a\in (c,d)$ such that $f(a)=b$. $\implies$ $a^{n}=b$. Since $a\in (c,d)$, $a>0$.

Proving Uniqueness of $a$:

Suppose $a$ is not unique. Then $\exists$ a $p\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(p)=b$ $\implies a^{n}= p^{n}$ $\implies p=\pm a$. If $p=-a$, then $p$ is negative since $a$ is positive. So, the only possible positive solution of $a^{n}=b$ is $p=a$. Hence uniqueness.

I just want to check if proof is rigorous enough and if there are any loopholes in the proof.

Comment: What do you mean by "By Archimedean Property of reals, we can find $f(c) < b < f(d)$"?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, I mean $f(c), f(d)\in  \Bbb R$, so it is possible to find  $b\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(c)<b<f(d)$

Comment: But you're not allowed to choose $b$, it's fixed at the beginning of the problem before any $c$ and $d$ enter the picture. What you would need to know in order to apply the Intermediate Value Theorem is that for any $b > 0$ there exist $c$ and $d$ such that $c^n < b < d^n$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, Can you present a proof please or maybe modify my proof?

Answer (score 0):

First show $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^n=\infty$. That is, $\forall M>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $x^n>M, \forall x>N$.

Given $b>0$, let $f(x)=x^n$ note $f(0)=0$. By above argument, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $x^n>b, \forall x>N$, hence $f(N+1)>b$. Then consider $f$ on $[0,N+1]$, and apply intermediate value theorem.

By uniqueness, you only need to show $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @ John, but if $x<1$, then $lim_{n->\inf}$ $x^{n}\neq $infinity

Comment: @Martin I mean $x\to \infty$ not $n$.